# 18.04 No mouse buttons work

Tags: mouse, 18.04

I can login.  I was previously unable to click on the 'next' button on the 'welcome to 18.04' splash after login to finally get that off of my screen.  But now I can't do anything.

My USB mouse cursor moves, but no buttons work; left, middle, right.  I have tried two different mice(?) but still no joy.  The left button works fine on the login purple screen, but then it no long works on the desktop.  I have (login settings) tried both the GNOME on Xorg, an the Ubuntu, but both have the same problem - buttons don't work!

Looking at other suggestions on other answers, I did `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` but no joy.  I also do `sudo apt update` and `upgrade`, but no joy.

I'm able to login to the computer that has the problem via ssh from another system that is running 17.10.

So my 18.04 computer is totally down and unable to be used.  How can I debug/fix this?

Comment: mouse or trackpad? Please tell exactly what hardware it is

Comment: if you can access your Ubuntu desktop, press CTRL + ALT + T to open a terminal and type `sudo cat /dev/input/mice` -> press your mouse button -> if your terminal displays (some exotics) ASCII symbols when you pressed buttons (it does it when you move the mouse too, press the button without moving the mouse), so Ubuntu recognize the mouse, but not your desktop; ifnot, Ubuntu had a big problem about your mouse

Comment: cmak.fr - as above, USB MOUSE.  Notice it works on login.  Thanks!

Comment: damadam: tried opening terminal session from both Xorg and Ubuntu setting on login just now; neither will give me a terminal on CTRL+ALT+T.  Doing it via ssh shows what looks to be binary on all three buttons: left, right, middle.  So system is getting the mouse buttons, just not acting on them.

Comment: Have you installed **any** GNOME extensions... like **Dashboard to Dock**?

Comment: heynnema: No.  As I understand it, "Dashboard to Dock" is associated with Apple; I'm not Apple.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Searching the Internet, I found a suggestion to edit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf, and to uncomment the "#WaylandEnable=false", but it didn't correct anything.  I've returned it to commented-out, as it was when I edited it, and rebooted.

Comment: Regarding Wayland:  if I execute "echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE", I get a blank line.

Comment: I completely forgot to mention: I was running 17.10 and this is an upgrade to 18.04

Comment: No, **Dashboard to Dock** is a GNOME extension that causes problems similar to what you describe. You didn't answer my question about other GNOME extensions. Make sure to respond to me with @heynnema, or I'll miss your reply.

Comment: @heynnema thanks for the insight.  I can't say definitively, but I think the release 17.10 was the first time I've used GNOME; I don't recall adding any extension.  I hate to ask, but what would be some extensions that are popular?  I did install 'Tweaks' in 17.10, so maybe yes.  Added GNOME to the search so found some insight.  From what I observed via google, no I did not install any 'dashboard to dock' extension.  Thanks!  If nothing else, it was an interesting side excursion!

Comment: Performing " less /proc/bus/input/devices", I get the following output for the mouse: I: Bus=0003 Vendor=413c Product=3012 Version=0111
N: Name="Dell Dell USB Optical Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/0003:413C:3012.0001/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=103
B: MSC=10

Comment: Just noticed that after login, keyboard does't work either.  Both are USB, neither going through a USB hub.

Comment: @heynneme: It looks like I was wrong.  syslog show: gnome-shell/extensions/workspaces-to-dock  : JS ERROR: TypeError: this._porthole is undefined#012myThumbnailsBox<._getPreferredWidth@/home/superben/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/workspaces-to-dock@passingthru67.gmail.com

Comment: @heynneme: you were right, it was the workspaces-to-dock that was the problem.  Renaming directory ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions'workspaces-to-doc.... fixed.  THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

It was the **Workspaces to Dock** GNOME extension that caused the mouse and keyboard issues. It's a known problem with this extension. Rename the directory back, and then it should be uninstalled at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/

**Update #1:**

It seems that the latest update to this GNOME extension has fixed this problem.

**Update #2:**

Although the extension update fixed the original problem, it created new problems with the workspace overview.

Answer (score 0):

@heynneme: you were right, it was the workspaces-to-dock that was the problem. Renaming directory ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions'workspaces-to-doc.... fixed. THANKS! – user2565677 2 hours ago